# Unable to login to Outlook after adding log on to on MacBook

Tags: windows, security, outlook

I am trying to add log on to host to users who are using MacBook. In windows it is working without problem because I am adding specific servers to their log on. But whenever I am trying to login to Outlook in MacBook it says username password are incorrect. Is there are any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is solved after you set the option as let users log on from all computers.

Ahh. I've never seen this setting before. Did you set it in EAC?
Would you mind to share a screenshot of the option?

PR: If the issue has been solved, please do not forget to mark helpful reply as an answer so that it will help other community numbers when they get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the account profile maybe corrupted. Try recreating the profile in control panel.
I found a similar thread for your reference.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cant-log-in-to-outlook-from-mac-laptop/c7c85b50-0c31-4e5a-bcde-df203c679520

Please also check the Microsoft's solution to fix it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/i-can-t-connect-to-my-exchange-account-in-outlook-for-mac-7b82e69b-3c4d-4f1a-be87-9d97c1ef6e16

Comment: I tried to delete the profile, but it didn't work for me. The only solution I found is to let users log on from all computers. It works without a problem.

Comment: How's everything going now? Do not forget to mark a helpful reply as an answer so that you can close this thread. Thanks!